# error: unknown LVM metadata header?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm

I Upgraded to Ubuntu12.10, and when grub ran through the upgrade it gave me these errors:

```
  root@secure:/usr/share/grub# update-grub
  error: unknown LVM metadata header.
  error: unknown LVM metadata header.
  Generating grub.cfg ...
  error: unknown LVM metadata header.
  error: unknown LVM metadata header.
  error: unknown LVM metadata header.
  error: unknown LVM metadata header.
  error: unknown LVM metadata header.
  error: unknown LVM metadata header.
  error: unknown LVM metadata header.
  error: unknown LVM metadata header.
  ...
```

I haven't rebooted yet, scared that if I do, the pc won't boot correctly.. how do I fix this? Here is a copy of logs that'll be helpful, to see whats going on.. http://pastie.org/4389403

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a pre-release Linux distribution. You should *expect* that it will have bugs, crash, destroy all your data, etc. You absolutely should **not** attempt to install it on your primary computer unless you're actively developing or testing it and you are willing to live with complete data loss on that machine.

If you *were* actively developing or testing it, you would report bugs on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal).

Comment: same issue occurred when I attempted to install kernel 3.5 on the previous install, hoping the upgrade would fix things.